# MySQL and PHP: Using SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I am trying to acquire a row-level lock for a table in a database that prevents any future sessions from reading that row until the lock is released.

To accomplish this, I've been trying to use the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` syntax on an indexed column, but I can't seem to prevent other sessions from reading that row when they use the exact same query.

Is there something more I need to do? I'm using MySQL 5.5, PHP 7, and the table in question is Innodb.

To elaborate, the flow is thus:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE;
... (PHP stuffs)
UPDATE tbl SET value = 'xyz' WHERE id = 1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Subsequent requests will also run the exact same lines of code, but I would like one request to block the others from starting until it's committed the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the MySql docs about the InnoDB lock types?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking.html

Comment: I don't believe those apply when using `FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: Welcome to SO @cesarandré Please avoid link only answers. Use the comment section for that, if not able to comment, gather reputation first.

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reasons I could not get the SELECT FOR UPDATE to work well with my codes (still trying though) but meanwhile, I had to implement my own lock on an innoDB table. The issue was avoidance of transaction balances mix-ups for a payment gateway I am developing. The following pseudo code can help anyone looking for an **alternative transaction locks**.

```
//Add transaction lock flag column into your table
//TXN_LOCK; Defaulted to Integer 0;

//FIRST: Select the balance and current txn-lock value  
$stopCount = 1;
$dbBalance = $tnxLock = 0;
$failureFlag = false; 
do {
    //run the select query; get values including $dbBalance and $tnxLock 
    //increment the counter; we won't run this forever          
    $stopCount++;
    if($stopCount > 3){
        //only a few trials
        $failureFlag = true;
        break;
    }
    //lock table, it looks free
    if($tnxLock == '0'){
        //update table set tnxLock = 1;         
    }
}while ($tnxLock > 0);  

if($failureFlag){
    //log and end; return failure   
    return false;
}else {
    //proceed 
}   
//--------------------------------

//now do you mathematics 
//add or subtract value from the balance

//then update the table; at the same time update the lock-code back to zero 
//UPDATE table set balance = xxx, tnxLock = 0;

//NOTE: This can be set as a function, 
//   with right params and flags of doing both credits and debits and 
//   called each time such operation is needed for consistency
//   Normal begin and commit transaction can also be added for more stability
```